# external javascript link not working

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, external

I can't figure out why my external javaScript won't link to my html code. What am I doing wrong? With my input function I am trying to concatenate 2 Strings and output the new String in the empty text field.

Thanks in advance guys!

## HTML (index.html)

```
<head>
<title> Free GPA Calculator </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gpa_style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gpacalc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="courseAddForm">
        <h1> Free GPA Calculator </h1>
        <form id="courseAdd">
            <label for="course" class="info" > Course </label>
            <input type="text" name="course" /><br />
            <label for="credits" class="info"> Number of Credits </label>
            <input type="text" name="credits" /><br />
            <label for="grade" class="info"> Letter Grade </label>
            <input type="text" name="grade" /><br />
            <div id="buttons">
                <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="input()" />
                <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
             </div>
            <input type="text" name="exp" />
        </form>
</body>
```

## JavaScript (gpacalc.js)

```
function input() {
    var doc = document.getElementById("courseAdd");
    var course = doc.course.value;
    var credits = doc.credits.value;
    var grade = doc.grade.value;
    doc.exp.value = course + credits;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. Are index.html and gpacalc.js in the same folder? Or maybe you have to chmod gpacalc.js if your webservice has no access to it

Comment: Everything looks fine to me, is the `gpacalc.js` in the same directory? If you have it in a folder then you need to add /foldername/gpacalc.js

Comment: you should close div `courseAddForm`

Comment: try using `/gpacalc.js`

Comment: And you can always use the net tab of Firebug (or of the built-in debugger of FF or Chrome). There you can check if you have access to the js file

Comment: Add `alert('hello')` inside `input()` and check if the alert works

Comment: or just log `doc`..i think you are getting a null value.

Comment: I have checked the javascript and it works just fine, I can only assume you have your javacript file `gpacalc.js` in a different directory.

Comment: Yes, all my files are in the same directory. I believe @balping is right because I tried using firebug to debug but I can't even start the debugging process for some reason. Sorry, I am new to this. How would can I fix this?

Comment: Try to open gpacalc.js in your browser (replace index.html at the end of the url to gpacalc.js). And see if you get an error message. If it cannot be loaded, try `chmod 777 gpacalc.js` (chmod 777 is not very secure anyway)

Comment: i checked your code and the error it is saying is `input() is not defined`..check my solution please..

Comment: @balping Your solution worked, my browser didn't have access to it. It works now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/r7tr0p35/)

Use jQuery as follows for the click function and it works!!!

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function input() {

        var doc = document.getElementById("courseAdd");
        var course = doc.course.value;
        var credits = doc.credits.value;
        var grade = doc.grade.value;
        doc.exp.value = course + credits;
    }
    $('#myButton').on('click', input);
});
```

Also, i have replaced

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="input()" />
```

with

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="myButton" />
```

in your HTML.

Comment: Why use jQuery when the existing javascript doesn't have any errors? This isn't a solution to why the external javascript file isn't working.

Comment: Ok i understood..i am trying to debug it..meanwhile i just thought to provide him with a solution.. @NewToJS